# NPX command not running in Azure pipeline

Tags: npm, azure-pipelines, cypress, npx

**I need your help**
I was trying to run my cypress test cases which I generally run using command
**"npx cypress run"**
so I tried to have the same command in tasks when I created Azure pipeline

after NPM Install

I even tried installing npx via
npm task and custom command "**npm install nx"**
and this causing the below issue so can anyone suggest to me how to proceed in this case

"##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory

##[error]Error: **Npm failed with return code: 1**
"

[image]

Comment: Is your pipeline already providing `npm`? The error message looks like what is being passed is `npm npm install nx`, which would lead me to believe there's an unneeded `npm` being added. If you're specifying `npm install nx`, could you try doing `install nx`?

Answer (score 2):

From the error screenshot, it shows that you are using the Npm Task and running the command: `npm npm install nx`.

The command is invalid.

To solve this issue, you need to remove the `npm` in the **NPM task -> Command and arguments** .

Refer to the following sample:

YAML Pipeline:

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install nx'
```

Classic Pipeline:

[image]